# Remove duplication and merge objects in a list

Tags: java, list

I want to remove duplication and merge objects in a list, I just figured out how to solve it using SQL, like

```
select a.id,GROUP_CONCAT(a.text) from table a GROUP BY a.id;
```

but actually, I want to solve it with **Java**, Is there any way to do it?

here is input:

```
input = [{id: 1, text:123}, {id: 1, text: 456}, {id:1, text:789}, {id:2, text:111}]
```

here is output:

```
output = [{id: 1, text:[123, 456, 789]}, {id: 2, text:[111]}]
```

Comment: The first approach and a very short solution would be to put the values into a Set. That eliminates duplicates. But I´m not sure if your question is also how to convert your SQL results into Java objects?

Comment: no, I want to solve the problem with Java rather than using sql

Comment: so please show us what you tried so far in JAVA to solve this

Comment: You can iterate over input and put the texts in a LinkedHashMap, if the entry is already present do the concatenation, when done build a new list of record iterating over the Map.